# I/Choreographer: Skipped 38 frames

Tags: android

I'm starting to developing in Android and I was wondering if there is another way to change the font of the text.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.escena_1/* .activity_main*/);


/* IM USING THIS */
        TextView tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewx);
        Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/OpenSans-Light.ttf");
        tx.setTypeface(custom_font);



    }
}
```

Well, I don't have anything else besides that. But I'm getting the error "Skipped 38 frames".

Comment: Do you mean from the XML directly?

Comment: out of curiousity,  is this a samsung device?

Comment: As far as i know this is not an error and may occur on any application start. It's simply the the App, launching during high CPU load (caused by the installation through ADB, Package Manager etc.) and skipping some animation frames.

Comment: post your xml layout

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answers.

This is my mainactivity.java

```js
package com.example.asus.app1;

    import android.graphics.Typeface;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    
    import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
    import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.escena_1/* .activity_main*/);


        TextView tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewx);
        Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/OpenSans-Light.ttf");
        tx.setTypeface(custom_font);

        TextView texto_2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        texto_2.setTypeface(custom_font);


        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
      ///  client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }


    }
```

And this is mya "escena_1" xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.Dialog.NoActionBar">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/image_1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imagen_1"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="83dp" />
<!--StayWithMe12!-->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="206dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/text_1"
        android:id="@+id/textViewx"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="33sp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/text_2"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewx"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp" />

</RelativeLayout>`enter code here`
```